# Which or what in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Should I use `which` or `what` here and why? What should be the tense of the verb `postpone`?

> Don’t miss the opportunity to live life to the full **which/what** you constantly postpone year after year.

Comment: **what** means **the thing which**, so either _to live to the full what you..._ or _to live life to the full which you..._  ... IMO

Comment: *Neither* would work in the sentence construction that you have. Also note *which* is complemented by *that*, not *what*. *What* has no place here at all.

Comment: @Jason Bassford [Examlpes are scarce](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&hl=ru&ei=2bQ_XOm6N8HRsAHPzZjoCg&q=%22to+live+life+which%22&oq=%22to+live+life+which%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0..118014...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.6WvXgErxpRg) but is _How can I live life which is full of sadness,defeats and setbacks_ incorrect?

Comment: @MvLog Your sentence doesn't have the same construction as the sentence in the question, nor does it use *what*, which is what I objected to. But if I were critiquing it, I'd say it should be ***a*** *life*. And although not wrong as it is, I think using the singular *defeat* and *setback* would make it sound better.

Comment: @Jason Bassford You said _neither_, didn't you? Now, what's wrong with _the opportunity to live (a) life to the full, which you have been constantly postponing for years_?

Comment: @Jason Bassford Now I see there is an ambiguity—what does the wh-clause refer to: the opportunity or a life? If we take it to be _a life_ then it's possible to construe the sentence as _the opportunity to live to the full what you have been..._ similarly to [_to live what you believe_](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&hl=ru&ei=grE_XKXgBsSRsgH705yoDg&q=%22to+live+what+you+believe%22&oq=%22to+live+what+you+believe%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i5i10i30j0i5i30j0i8i30l2.34145.40165..46114...1.0..0.97.941.13......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i160j0i8i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i7i5i10i30j33i10.0DCaYTJIfIw)

Answer (score 2):

In you example sentence

> Don’t miss the opportunity to live life to the full **which** you constantly postpone year after year.

The speaker is admonishing the listener to not waste "***opportunities to live life to the full***". "***Which***" refers back to this reference in your sentence and the speaker goes further to say that *you* have postponed those opportunities "***year after year***".